# how to get each and every log of single sql file in output

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a batch file which runs all the .sql files in a directory and stores the logs in outputfile by creating a txt file as sql_file_name_output_.txt .

However when a single .sql files contains multiple insert statments or update statements one after the other 
eg:

```
    INSERT INTO Customers values(009,'City', 25);
    INSERT INTO Customers values(010,'City', 25);
    INSERT INTO Customers values(014,'City', 25);
```

I get only "(1 row(s) affected)" . Whereas it should have shown :

```
    (1 row(s) affected)
    (1 row(s) affected)
    (1 row(s) affected)
```

. I would need your help in this .
My batch script is below :

```
    @echo off
    SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.sql') do (
    call sqlcmd -S AMRVSP000000318 -i %%a  -o"%%~na_sqloutput.txt" 
    )pause
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine when I try your code.